# Popup with new url after click on image

Tags: javascript, html, css, popup

I want to add popup windows to photo gallery. On Facebook, when you open a photo, you have new URL but with parent page in background.
Please give me an example (code) to create a nice popup window.

Thank you in advance for doing my work.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow...please [CLICK HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for a guide to posting questions in our community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Colorbox plugin](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/). Set the **href** property to the url of your picture's location.